# Why is there no search field for Module, Directory or File on Issue-Page

Tags: sonarqube

How can I search for Modules in Issues, if I have selected multiple Projects or if I have a Project with multiple Modules. If you have more then 15 Modules, you cannot search for them. Same problem with Directory and File.
Look here: [Screenshot_SonarQube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kdIC.jpg)

sonarqube Version 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open request for feature on that topic: please go and vote for [SONAR-6081](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6081).